# Uniform continuity property

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f_t$ (and $f$) is uniformly continuous on $[0,T] \times S$, where $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact.

> The uniform continuity allows us to estimate 
>   $$\lVert f(t+k, \cdot) - f(t, \cdot) - f_t(t, \cdot)k \rVert_\infty = \lVert k \int_0^1 f_t(t+rk, \cdot) - f_t(t,\cdot)\;dr\rVert_\infty \leq k\epsilon$$
>   for $k$ small enough.

I'm a bit stumped. The second equality I can see by just integrating it out. But why the estimate hold? What's the intuition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\lVert (t+rk,s)-(t,s)\rVert\leq |rk|\leq |k|$ if $0\leq r\leq 1$. So apply the definition of uniform continuity to $\varepsilon$ to get a corresponding $\delta$. Then take $|k|\leq \delta$.